# Straight forward add days to current date javascript

Tags: javascript

I apologize as I'm sure this question has been answered already but there's so many different solutions from different years that my head is just spinning from viewing all the different solutions. But can someone please help with providing a straight forward javascript solution to display (x) days after current date?

All I'm trying to accomplish is having a notice on a page - "We are currently accepting bookings for **March XX, 2017** or after" at the top.

OR is there anything I can to the code below to make it add (X) days as I'm using this to show current date.

```
var MONTH_NAME = ['January', 'Febuary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
              'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
function showTime() {
function twoDigit(n) {
    return ('0' + n).slice(-2);
}
function iso8601(date) {
    return date.getFullYear() +
           '-' + twoDigit(1 + date.getMonth()) +
           '-' + twoDigit(date.getDate()) +
           'T' + twoDigit(date.getHours()) +
           ':' + twoDigit(date.getMinutes());
}
function en_US(date) {
    var h = date.getHours() % 12;
    return MONTH_NAME[date.getMonth()] +
           ' '  + date.getDate() +
           ', ' + date.getFullYear();
}

var timeEl = document.getElementById('time');
if (timeEl !== null) {
    var now = new Date();
    timeEl.innerHTML = en_US(now);
    timeDiv.setAttribute('datetime', iso8601(now));
}
};
setInterval(showTime, 1000);
```

Please and thank you.

Comment: This is a suggestion more than an answer. Don't try and re-invent the wheel, use something which does this for you: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Hey Doug, thanks for the suggestion and I've definitely looked into it but I'm just starting with javascript and seeing the code from moment.js and how powerful it could be, I just got overwhelmed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setDate` and `getDate` methods to solve your problem. Take a look at `addDays` method I have written. Hope this helps.

```js
var MONTH_NAME = ['January', 'Febuary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
  'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'
];

function showTime() {
  function twoDigit(n) {
    return ('0' + n).slice(-2);
  }

  function iso8601(date) {
    return date.getFullYear() +
      '-' + twoDigit(1 + date.getMonth()) +
      '-' + twoDigit(date.getDate()) +
      'T' + twoDigit(date.getHours()) +
      ':' + twoDigit(date.getMinutes());
  }

  function en_US(date) {
    var h = date.getHours() % 12;
    return MONTH_NAME[date.getMonth()] +
      ' ' + date.getDate() +
      ', ' + date.getFullYear();
  }
  
  function addDays(date, days){
     var newDate = new Date(date.getTime());
     newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + days);
     return newDate;
  }

  var timeEl = document.getElementById('time');
  if (timeEl !== null) {
    var now = new Date();
    timeEl.innerHTML = en_US(now) + ' to ' + en_US(addDays(now, 15));
    timeEl.setAttribute('datetime', iso8601(now));
  }
};

setInterval(showTime, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: Hey Ajai, this is exactly what I need. Thanks for the quick response. I actually just needed the future date to display. But I was able to spot the current date and it was pretty easy to remove it. Thank you!